# How to databind (custom) chart in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I want to filter my chart using some text in combo box into my sql, then my sql will be my data source to my chart... but Im having a hard time with this (Im new to charts)

so far this is what i've done:

```
Dim rdr As OleDbDataReader
Dim CN1 As New OleDbConnection(cs)

        CN1.Open()
        adp = New OleDbDataAdapter()
        adp.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT (ItemName) AS [Item Name], (ItemSize) AS [Item Size], (ConsumedDate) AS [Date], (ConsumedQuantity) AS [Quantity] from ConsumedItems where ItemName = '" & cbxItem.Text & _
                               "' AND ItemSize = '" & cbxSize.Text & "'", CN1)
'chrConsumption.Series("ActualConsumption").Points.AddXY(rdr.GetInt16("ConsumedQuantity"), rdr.GetString("ItemName"))

chrConsumption.Series("ActualConsumption").XValueMember = "ConsumedItems.ConsumedDate" 
chrConsumption.Series("ActualConsumption").YValueMembers = "ConsumedItems.ConsumedQuantity"
```

The code above is my first attempt which is not working... The code below is working but the x axis doesnt display the date as month

```
        Try

        Dim CN1 As New OleDbConnection(cs)

        CN1.Open()
        adp = New OleDbDataAdapter()
        adp.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT (ConsumedDate) AS [Date], (ConsumedQuantity) AS [Quantity] from ConsumedItems where ItemName = '" & cbxItem.Text & _
                               "' AND ItemSize = '" & cbxSize.Text & "' AND ConsumedDate BETWEEN #" & dtpDateFrom.Value & "# AND #" & dtpDateTo.Value & "#", CN1)
        ds = New DataSet("ds")
        adp.Fill(ds)
        dtable = ds.Tables(0)

        chrConsumption.Series("ActualConsumption").XValueMember = "Date"
        chrConsumption.Series("ActualConsumption").YValueMembers = "Quantity"
        chrConsumption.DataSource = dtable
        chrConsumption.DataBind()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
```

this is the output of the graph
[image]